# Is it possible to invoke the main method of a test class through pytest?

Tags: python, appium, pytest, python-unittest

I have a test class `test_enrollment.py` that defines a set of tests, and has a main method which uses a generator to generate a new custom test class. In a simpler form, it looks like:

```
import json
import unittest

import front_end_tests.generator


class EnrollmentTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_new_student_registration(self):
        # test definition here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    front_end_tests.generator.generate_and_run_tests(EnrollmentTests)
```

The way I normally run this test class is by calling `python test_enrollment.py`. If I wanted to run this same test file with `pytest` instead, is there a way to call the file in a way where the main method still gets called?

Answer (score 0):

I thought you can`t.
To solve this problem, you just need to move

```
front_end_tests.generator.generate_and_run_tests(EnrollmentTests)
```

To

```
def setUpModule():
    front_end_tests.generator.generate_and_run_tests(EnrollmentTests)
```

`test_enrollment.py` look like this:

```
import json
import unittest

import front_end_tests.generator

def setUpModule():
    front_end_tests.generator.generate_and_run_tests(EnrollmentTests)

class EnrollmentTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_new_student_registration(self):
        # test definition here
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and just type:

```
pytest
```